# Powershell remote installation has problems with setup of util:ServiceConfig wix element during installation

Tags: powershell, wix

I would like to ask you if there is any other way how to setup parts of wix element - util:ServiceConfig other than in MS installer?

I need to configure this parts of wix element:

```
   FirstFailureActionType="restart"
   SecondFailureActionType="restart"
   ThirdFailureActionType="restart"
   ResetPeriodInDays="1"
   RestartServiceDelayInSeconds="60"
```

When I make comment from whole "util:ServiceConfig" part of code and build installer, everything is fine and remote installation will be executed without issues.

I am trying to find way how to configure it besides Microsoft installer but google did not give me desired answers.
Or is there any other solution how to make PowerShell remote installation somehow process that configuration?(I mean user rights and permissions or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for this problem by myself.

I have created Custom action which is executing command calling "sc.exe failure" and configure FailureActions in that command.
I deleted whole util:ServiceConfig wix element and replaced it with this:

```
<CustomAction Id="ServiceRestarter"
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
              ExeCommand="&quot;[SystemFolder]sc.exe&quot; failure &quot;ServiceName&quot; reset= 86400 actions= restart/60000/restart/60000/restart/60000"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='ServiceRestarter' After='InstallFinalize'>(NOT Installed)</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Now my PowerShell script doesn't have problem with remote installation of .msi package. Cheers, I hope it will help someone else than me.